# How to add sidebar at single.php in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a problem when it comes to adding sidebar at single.php. I already included

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

But it seems to be appear below and the content(Blog post) still at the middle of the whole page. I've tried to check all of the previous forum but none of them helped me to figure this out.

Here's my single.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package Tesseract
*/

get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary" class="full-width-page">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

        <?php tesseract_post_nav(); ?>

        <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
        ?>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: can you try putting <?php get_sidebar(); ?> above the loop and see if it works

Comment: @Satya, I put the sidebar at the top but the content moved lower than the sidebar. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most logical reason for this to happen is that there isn't enough room for both the main content and the sidebar to appear next to each other. Check the width of your sections in your stylesheet and make the necessary changes to the styles.

Comment: Hi sir Yavor. Yeah that's my first approached dealing with that problem. I've tried to make a <div> wrapper for the container with a value of 100% and cut them into 70% for the content and 30% for the sidebar but nothing seems to worked. :(

Comment: Hahaha Sir sir sir! What a good news. I just need to take some bath and relax after that, I think again from your suggested ideas. Haha Yeah Voila! I've done it. I just make it again. I created wrapper and divided them in to two cuts. :D God bless and thank you sir. I consumed a lot of hours finding to fix it but all I need to do is to take some bath and a little bit rest :D

Comment: I'm grad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you create the sidebar in the admin and then call that sidebar where you want.Following is the code for calling sidebar

```
<ul id="sidebar">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' ); ?>
```

Use following link to know more about how to create a sidebar
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Comment: What do you mean sir? I'll paste the <?php dynamic_sidebar('right-sidebar'); ?> at my single.php? Am I right?

Comment: first create sidebar in the admin after that past the id of the sidebar in the dyanamic_sidebar()

Comment: Actually sir, my theme already have sidebar.php. It works at the other page but the problem is, when I try to add sidebar at single.php, it does not work? :(